# Why bootstrap behave like mobile in ie7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

i am using bootstrap 3 and its behave like mobile version css in ie8. Please suggest what to do...

i am using modernizere and respond js:

```
modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js
```

Comment: I am confused: is the last paragraph an answer?

Comment: forget about last para

Comment: here i am describing the issue @StefanoSanfilippo, everything is gonna become full width in IE8 same like we are showing it in mobile version.